# Simulate indentation with uncrustify

Tags: git, code-cleanup, uncrustify

I'm writing a simple git hook to ensure that all the committed code is corrected indented.
We use uncrustify to indent our code and the this the script we run before every commit

```
find -name "*.[hm]" -exec uncrustify -c uncrustify.cfg {} --replace --no-backup \;
```

I'm looking for a way to refuse a push if the code is not *uncrustified*. I can try to compare the original version of the file with the *uncrustified* version but it seems very slow because i have to generate a new version of the file, check and delete after the check.

I'm wondering if uncrustify has some hiddent switch just to test if a file should be formatted.

thanks.

This is the function i'm using to test if a file is already indented

```
function isIndented() {

    FILE1=$1

    uncrustify -c uncrustify.cfg "$FILE1" --mtime

    FILE2=${FILE1}.uncrustify

    if cmp -s "$FILE1" "$FILE2"
    then
       RESULT=1
    else
       RESULT=0
    fi

    rm "$FILE2"
    echo $RESULT
```

}